# JavaScript event management, handling global vs lots of listeners

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've been developing a framework for web apps based upon and MVC style methodology.

It's more of a general question to the JS gurus amongst you:
if you have lots of views each with various event listeners, does this slow the overall responsiveness down? I'm toying with the idea of creating a global event manager which drills down to active views/objects based on mouse position & focus then calls methods instead of creating lots of listeners all over the place for each and every view.

Would this improve the overall responsiveness of the app or is this largely pointless?

It's hard to create unit tests to check and I'm hoping for some insight from others.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/delegate-on-vs-bind-5/2 something like this?

Comment: thanks for the link it's not really what I meant. I'm looking for answers regarding removing all page listeners in favour of a global event delegator for the whole app

Answer (score 0):

You still need to hang those methods to the events, aren't you? Actually I think and hope that event driven paradigm was designed and implemented as a best solution...
I don't know how exactly are events implemented in browsers, but I expect also some kind of global layer which captures all events and then it propably searches if any listener is registered for it and then it propably goes through DOM and checks the selector. And when everything fits, it calls provided method..

Answer (score 0):

actually calling `addEventListener` once and calling the functions in the `callbacks` array will be faster than using multiple `addEventListener` but this will only make sense if you have more than 20 event functions